# Can dnsmasq return a NOERROR for a AAAA request on a synth domain?

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-hosting, dnsmasq

I have an instance of dnsmasq running that is utilizing the synth-domain option. It's working great for A queries, however, it returns an NXDOMIN for a AAAA query. Here's an example of how to replicate.

Running dnsmasq:

```
dnsmasq --keep-in-foreground --synth-domain=example.com,192.168.1.0/24,ip-
```

A query:

```
dig ip-192-168-1-100.example.com @127.0.0.1 a

; <<>> DiG 9.11.1-P3 <<>> ip-192-168-1-100.example.com @127.0.0.1 a
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 45136
;; flags: qr aa rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ip-192-168-1-100.example.com.  IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
ip-192-168-1-100.example.com. 0 IN  A   192.168.1.100

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Wed Jul 19 14:24:52 PDT 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 73
```

AAAA query:

```
$ dig ip-192-168-1-100.example.com @127.0.0.1 aaaa

; <<>> DiG 9.11.1-P3 <<>> ip-192-168-1-100.example.com @127.0.0.1 aaaa
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 5180
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ip-192-168-1-100.example.com.  IN  AAAA

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Wed Jul 19 14:33:45 PDT 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 57
```

I would like to have dnsmasq return an empty NOERROR response instead of an NXDOMAIN in this situation. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not without modifying the dnsmasq code itself. What you see is the correct behaviour: If the resolver doesn't know the answer, and is authoritative for the given domain as is the case for such defined `synth-domain` construct, it is obligated to respond with `NXDOMAIN`. Furthermore, it would be an ill-formed response (no error and no `AN`, `NS`, or `AR` records).